# parsing a json array does not give me the values

Tags: php

below is my 'script.json' file with json array and i want the values of `webUserid` and `webPassword`

```
{
   "totalSize":2,
   "webUserId":"abc",
   "webPassword":"def",
   "operation":"send",
   "testMode":true,
   "records":[
      {
         "phoneNumber":"1908908399",
         "message":"Happy Birthday",
         "Id":"a0YL0000008QYunMAG",
         "deviceId":"ABCDEFXABCDEF"
      }

   ]
}
```

I tried below one but not getting the result

```
 <?php
       $jsonString=file_get_contents("script.json");
       $decoded=json_decode($jsonString,true);
       foreach($decoded->data as $name){
            echo $name->totalSize;
       }
?>
```

Comment: its the json array and i am trying using foreach but not getting the values

Comment: `parsing a json array does not give me the values` what does it give you? Post the code you're currently using to parse it

Comment: @Zarif do not post code in comments, please edit the question.

Comment: @Zarif you do not have any `data` in your json string.

Comment: @Zarif the second parameter you're giving `json_decode` means it'll return an associative array instead of an object. Looks like you're trying to treat it as an object and I'm guessing your have a large `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` at the top of your page (or if you don't, in which case **turn errors on**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zarif, try the below code, its working 100%......... :)

```
<?php
   $jsonString=file_get_contents("script.json");
   $decoded=array(json_decode($jsonString,true));
   foreach($decoded as $name){
        echo $name['totalSize'];
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a foreach loop in your current example, as you only have one level.

Your main problem is you're trying to use the result of your [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as an object when you've previously stated you want the result as an associative array.

The 2nd param of `json_decode` specifies what format the return value is in, so as you've done

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

you'll receive an array, which you could access like

```
echo $decoded['totalSize'];
```

if you wanted to treat it as on object as you've done in your question, either state `false` or omit a 2nd param in json_decode (it's false by default anyway), and that'll let you do what you're trying to do:

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString);
$decoded->totalSize;
```

Answer (score -1):

lets say that

```
$myJSON = yourPostedJSON.

$myJSON = json_decode($myJSON, true);

echo $myJSON['webUserId'];
echo $myJSON['webPassword'];
```